# How can I find a sheet name by looking up a column

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to scripts (i.e a total novice).I'm trying to update a work tracker used by several members of a team. It basically logs cases on a separate tab for each person.

I have managed to set up a code that moves a row to another tab when a checkbox is ticked (i.e. when a case is closed they can automatically move the row of data to a "Closed" tab).
What I'm having trouble with is giving the team the option of moving it back should they close it in error. I can make it work but it only moves the data back to the named sheet in the script. How do I get it to find the sheet name by looking up the agent's name? The agents name is listed in column D.

Here is the code I've used this is where I believe I need the help:

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetName("Bob");

Many thanks
Loz

```html
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 5 or E
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Bob","Billy","Anna","Emma","Joe" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Closed" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetName("Bob");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHr07.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu28K.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Sorry, I've added it to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Getting sheet name from agent's column in sheet Closed I think

Assumed header row is one and Agent's column name is Agent

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ["Bob", "Billy", "Anna", "Emma", "Joe"];
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Closed");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if (sh.getName() == "Closed" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    //e.source.toast("Flag2");
    let hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(hA));
    let col = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h] = i + 1; });
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(col));
    //Logger.log(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col["Agent"]).getDisplayValue());
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col["Agent"]).getDisplayValue());
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

If you wish a better answer then please provide image of Closed and one of the Named Sheets

Comment: Hi @Cooper. Thanks so much for your help. It works from the named sheet to the 'Closed' sheet but not back the way. I've added images of the sheets as requested. Thank you!

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: Try it now.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are unchecking a checkbox in column E in the "Closed" sheet and want to move the row back to the original agent.  And the name of the agent or sheet name is in column D of that row.  Then you can do this.

```
let agent = e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
let targetSheet = ss.getSheetName(agent);
```

**Reference**

- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Comment: Thanks @TheWizEd. Could you tell me where to put that in the code and what to take out of my original one? I've tried it a couple of ways but neither works (sorry, just learning)

Comment: replace this `var targetSheet = ss.getSheetName("Bob");` with my snippet.  But your first check is wrong.  Do something like what @Cooper has shown `const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());`